# Flask - 400 Error with JSON request

Tags: python, flask

I have created the following simple flask app that displays the predicted value from a machine learning model and it renders the index.html as needed until I make the json.request. Then I receive a 400 error; here is my code:

works as needed from the command line, but need to display the prediction(s) in the browser. Can someone provide a quick starting point for me? Here is my code:

```
@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    predict = [data["session"],data["time"],data["amount"]] 
    predict = np.array(predict)
    predict = predict_request.reshape(1,-1)
    #make prediction
    with graph.as_default():
        area = keras_model_loaded.predict(predict)
        output = [area[0]] 
        return render_template('index.html', output = output) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Choose the port
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 9000))
    # Run locally
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=port)
```

Here is how I am generating the JSON:

```
response = rq.get('https:xyz')
data=response.json()

session = data['currently']['session']
time = data['currently']['time']
amount = data['currently']['amount']

url= "http://127.0.0.1:9000/predict"

post_data = json.dumps({'session': session, 'time': time, 'amount': amount})

r = rq.post(url,post_data)
```

Comment: 400 error is a bad request.  Do you have any debugging output?  My money is on a problem with json.

Comment: Just the bad request info from the server. Im posting info the /predict from another .py file, but the process works from the command line at the server, just not when I try to render a template.

Comment: Set `debug=True` in app.run() and try again.  That will output debugging information to the browser and help you pinpoint your problem.

Comment: Please add the code for the JSON request to your question as well.

Comment: Ive updated my post with the json info. here is what Im getting from debug: Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Answer (score 0):

The JSON data doesn't seem to reach the server as expected. Kindly try updating your requests code to:

```
post_data = {'session': session, 'time': time, 'amount': amount}

r = rq.post(url, json=post_data)
```

From official python-requests docs:

> Using the json parameter in the request will change the Content-Type in the header to application/json.